# How to do inter-process communication?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

We are doing multiprocessing in Python3 on Raspberry Pi3. We do mask detection, people counting and cough detection in processes. We have 3 processes for now. All have been described as functions. (`def mask ()`, .. `def cough ()` etc.) They all work at the same time, there is no problem here. The problem is that as a 4th process, we want to write a alarm function according to the information from these 3 processes.

Our goal is to print an error on the screen if an unwanted situation occurs in these 3 detections (such as wrong mask use, too many people count.). 4. As a process, we cannot use the values returned by other functions with if-else commands under the `alarm ()` function. I write the kind of summary of the code below. How can we use the data in the process? Now, `alarm()`  does not work properly.

```
def mask():
      while True:
         if problem:
            return True

def cough():
      while True:
         if problem:           
            return True
def alarm():
      while True:
        if mask():
           print("Eror1")
        elif cough():
           print("Error2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=cough,)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=mask,)
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=alarm,)

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Python docs on multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), especially the parts about [exchanging objects between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) and [sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes.).

If all you want to do is signal your main process when some conditions occur, an [`Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event) object should probably be enough. If you want to exchange more complex data between the processes, a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) would be better suited.

With the `Event` objects your code could look roughly like this:

```py
import multiprocessing
from random import random
import time


def mask(event):
    while True:
        if random() < 0.1:
            event.set()
        time.sleep(1)


def cough(event):
    while True:
        if random() < 0.2:
            event.set()
        time.sleep(1)


def alarm(events):
    while True:
        for i, event in enumerate(events, start=1):
            # wait for up to a second for the event to be set by the other process
            # and then wait for the next event
            if event.wait(1):
                print('Error ' + str(i))
                event.clear()


def main():
    e1 = multiprocessing.Event()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=mask, args=(e1,))
    p1.start()

    e2 = multiprocessing.Event()
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=cough, args=(e2,))
    p2.start()

    alarm([e1, e2])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```